# How to have Process spawned by ProcessBuilder run a callback on completion/termination?

Tags: java, callback, processbuilder

I'm writing a separate thread to monitor an OS process spawned by Java's `ProcessBuilder`. The process can sometimes get out of control. After a given timeout period, I want to kill the process if it's still running. I can paste my code in if it's helpful (please ask), but the only detail directly relevant to the question is that I'm using `Process::waitFor` to specify the timeout after which the process will be killed.

The problem is that this code design is relatively inefficient. As even the documentation for `Process::waitFor` says,

> ```
> The default implementation of this methods polls the {@code exitValue}
> to check if the process has terminated. Concrete implementations of this
> class are strongly encouraged to override this method with a more
> efficient implementation.
> ```

I'm thinking a much more efficient design would be to specify a callback to be executed after the process completes. I could execute my own timeout method that would kill the process if it were still running. But the callback, if run, would cancel the timeout kill method.

Can I implement a callback pattern for a process spawned by `ProcessBuilder`?

I'm looking at the `ProcessBuilder.start(Redirect[] redirects)` and wondering if I could just tack the execution of the callback at the end of this method. Problem is that the class is final, so I can't subclass it. I'd have to copy and modify. But I'd also have to duplicate such dependencies as `ProcessEnvironment` and `ProcessImpl`, which are not public, as well as being final. Ugh.

Is maybe there some way to extend the abstract class Process to use a callback? That class seems to have/be the only space left by the authors of Java for fixing up the inefficient code they've left.

Or perhaps there's another way to make `Process::waitFor` more efficient?

Comment: *The problem is that this code design is rather inefficient* The documentation doesn't say that.  It says the default implementation polls.   Did you look at the actual implementation to see how it works?  Both Windows and Unix-style systems have an efficient way to wait on process termination without polling.  If you can't find the source, it should be easy enough to decide empirically whether it's inefficient: spawn a process that sleeps for 10 minutes, have the parent wait, and watch the CPU usage.

Comment: @danglingelse, the comment reads,  "Concrete implementations of this class are strongly encouraged to override this method with a more efficient implementation." When the code's author says there's a problem, that's a pretty clear indication there's a problem. And yes, I'm looking at the source code. A callback is a more efficient design pattern than polling. As any parent on a long road trip with kids can tell you, repeated "Are we there yet?" queries is a waste of effort.

Comment: Right, But you need appropriate kernel support to detect process termination, which makes it a platform-specific issue.